Generating function of $\{a_n\}$
For each positive integer $n$, let $a_n$ be the number of ordered quadruples $(x ; y ; z ; t)$ satisfying $x+y+z+t=n$ such that $x, y, z, t \in \mathbb{N}=\{0;1;2\cdots\}$ and $y \geq$ $2 x ; z \geq 2 y ; t \geq 2 z$. Find the generating function for the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$.
I initially thought this problem could be solved using Euler's method for distributing candies, but I couldn't figure out how to handle the additional conditions in this problem.

Yes! $0 \in \mathbb{N}$

Also, the paper here seems like it discusses a generalization of this problem. That may amount to using a crane to crush a fly, but the methods presented there might be worth investigating.

While following up on my CW answer, I realized that this sequence appeared identical to A000929 over at OEIS. However, closer inspection reveals that this is only true up to $n=30$. In retrospect such a breakdown is not too strange---the GF for A000929 requires an infinite product rather than a finite one---but it's curious enough that I thought I should highlight it.

Write $y = 2x + a$, $z = 2y + b = 4x + 2a + b$, and $t = 2z + c = 8x + 4a + 2b + c$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ to see that the number of tuples $(x,y,z,t)$ satisfying the required conditions is the same as the number of tuples $(x,a,b,c)$ satisfying $15 x + 7a + 3b + c = n$. The generating function for this sequence is thus $$\frac{1}{(1-x^{15})(1-x^7)(1-x^3)(1-x)}.$$

Looking at the result I got more closely, it indeed agrees with yours upon simplifying. It also explains the similarity to the referenced OEIS sequence, which allows arbitrarily many parts rather than at most 4. (And why the disagreement starts at $n=30$, since $n=31=1+2+4+8+16$ is the first example involving five parts.)

I used Mathematica to implement the solution found in section 3 of Corteel and Savage, 2003. In the case at hand, this has the following parameters (using their notation):

$k=4$
$(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(8,4,2,1)$,
$(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)=(1,12,14,15)$

Inserting these parameters into Eq. 9 (page 12) of Corteel and Savage and doing some minor algebra then yields the generating function
\begin{align}
F(q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n q^n
&=\frac{(1 + q^3) (1 + q^6) (1 + q^7)}{(1-q) \left(1-q^{12}\right) \left(1-q^{14}\right) \left(1-q^{15}\right)}\\
&=1 + q + q^2 + 2 q^3 + 2 q^4 + 2 q^5 + 3 q^6 + 4 q^7 + 4 q^8 + 5 q^9+\cdots
\end{align}
(One can actually simplify this down to $F(q)=1/P(q)$ where $P(q)$ is some product of polynomials in $q$, but the resulting expression did not seem particularly revealing.)
These first ten terms agree with what Mathematica finds via a brute-force search:
Table[Count[Tuples[Range[0, n], {4}], {x_, y_, z_, t_} /; 
   x + y + z + t == n && t >= 2 z >= 4 y >= 8 x], {n, 0, 9}]

yields {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5} which agrees with the above.
The paper provides a proof of their GF, but it is sufficiently involved that I don't care to translate it into the present case myself. (If anyone wants to edit this answer to do so, feel free.)
Remarkably, the resulting integer sequence has overlap with the OEIS entry A000929. One definition for this sequence is the "number of partitions $p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_m = n$ (into positive parts) such that $2p_k \leq p_{k-1}$." The similarity to the given problem should be evident, but in fact the two sequences only agree up to $n=30$:

A000929: $1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,3,4\ldots, 35, 37, 41, \mathbf{45, 47, 51},...$
$a_n$: $1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, \ldots, 35, 37, 41, \mathbf{44, 46, 50},\ldots$

That the two cannot agree for all $n$ is evident from the fact $F(q)=1/P(q)$ consists of a finite number of polynomial factors, whereas the GF for A000929 is the infinite product $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1 - q^{2^i-1})^{-1}$. But why this breakdown occurs at this particular point in the expansion is not evident to me.

The Mathematica code to generate $F(q)$ is included here for completeness. Note that this code yields the numerator in expanded form, with the earlier factorized form then found by inspection.
k=4;
{a1,a2,a3,a4}={8,4,2,1};
{b1,b2,b3,b4}={1,12,14,15};
G[q_]:=Sum[q^(2 z2 + z2 + z3 + z4)
             *q^(b2 Ceiling[z3/a3 - z2/a2])
             *q^(b3 Ceiling[z4/a4 - z3/a3]),
               {z2, 0, a2 - 1}, {z3, 0, a3 - 1}, {z4, 0, a4 - 1}];
H[q_]:=((1 - q^b1)(1 - q^b2)(1 - q^b3)(1 - q^b4));
F[q_]:=G[q]/H[q]

